# Is there a way to set content for StackLayout or Grid from a StaticResource

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Looking at my XAML I notice areas which are basically duplicates of each other and since I like to keep it clean I was thinking if there was a way to reduce duplicate code in the XAML.

So what I'm looking to do is to be able to set the Content for a control like StackLayout, Grid, Frame etc.

I've created a Page level resource but I'm not sure how I can use it.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout x:Key="CommonDetails">
        <Label Text="First Name"/>
        <Label Text="Last Name"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <CommonDetails>
    <Label Text="Extra Uncommon Data"/>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout>
    <CommonDetails>
    <Label Text="Extra Uncommon Data"/>
    <Label Text="Extra Uncommon Data"/>
    <Label Text="Extra Uncommon Data"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Resources` you can define a `ControlTemplete` instead:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="commonDetails">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="First Name"/>
            <Label Text="Last Name"/>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And here comes the tricky part, since in order to consume that you will need a `ContentView`, but in your case a "normal" `ContentView` won't do the job since they accept only one `child`: you will have to create an special `ContentView` which accepts multiple views.

You do this as follows:

```cs
// Overriding the ContentProperty allows you 
// to have a ContentView that accepts multiple childs.
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Contents")]
public class View1 : ContentView
{
    StackLayout contentStack { get; } = new StackLayout();
    
    public IList<View> Contents { get => contentStack.Children; }

    public View1()
    {
        Content = contentStack;
    }
}
```

And with that in hand, the rest is really simple, since in any `Page` you can define a custom `ControlTemplate` and set it to your special `ContentView`, as follows

```xml
<local:View1 ControlTemplate="{StaticResource commonDetails}">
    <Label Text="Occupation1"/>
    <Label Text="Occupation2"/>
</local:View1>
```

And that is it, i you find this useful!

Comment: I chose this as the answer as the later one posted was very similar to this, however I like this one as it explains how to add multiple view children. I'll more than likely just combine them in a Grid or Stack view to avoid having to use this extra code, but its nice to know this for future. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1:**

You could use the control template.

```
 <!--  Grid Template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
            <Label
                Grid.Row="1"
                BackgroundColor="Accent"
                Text="Grid Template" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

If you want to bind the value for the template in difference page, you could use the `TemplateBinding`.

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"  />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Accent" Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.Name}" />

        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

For more details with the code sample, you could check the code i done before.
[How to add a grid view under Master-Detail detail page in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909866/how-to-add-a-grid-view-under-master-detail-detail-page-in-xamarin-forms)

**Solution2:**

An easy way is using custom control as model.

You could check the sample in the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58928433/11850033